# get values of Jtextfields when click OK in Dialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

My need is to display a tab in a JDialog (confirmDialog or inputDialog). The tab contains 2 JTextField per row. The display works fine :

[image]

but I don't know how to get the values of the JTextFields.

Here is the display code :

```
int size = model.getCheckedApplications().size();
// une ligne par application sélectionnée
layout = new GridLayout(size + 1, 3, 5, 5);
myPanel = new JPanel(layout);
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Application"));
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Version cadre"));
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Nouvelles natures"));
for (Application app : model.getCheckedApplications()) {
    myPanel.add(new JLabel(app.getCode88()));
    JTextField versionActuelleField = new JTextField(30);
    versionActuelleField.setName("versionActuelle"
            + app.getCode88());
    versionActuelleField.setText(app
            .getVersionCadreActuelle());

    JTextField nouvellesNaturesField = new JTextField(
            30);
    nouvellesNaturesField.setName("nouvellesNatures"
            + app.getCode88());

    myPanel.add(versionActuelleField);
    myPanel.add(nouvellesNaturesField);
}
result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
        "Valeurs de cette version",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Then I don't know how to get the values when the user clicks on the OK Button :

```
if (result == 0) { // The user clicks on the ok button
```

Comment: `JTextField.getText()` ???

Comment: @MatthewDiana yes but how can I get the right JTextField ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Best to pass a parent component when showing the option pane. That way the user cannot interact with the (parent) GUI until the option pane is dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them to some list that you store, so you can get at them again. Since you are adding them in reference to an application, I would suggest a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
private Map<Application, JTextField> nouvellesNaturesFields = new ArrayListMultimap<Application, JTextField>(); //Or Hashmap, if the key is unique
private Map<Application, JTextField> versionActuelleFields = new ArrayListMultiMap<Application, JTextField>();

public List<JTextField> getNouvellesNaturesFields() {
    return nouvellesNaturesFields ;
}

public List<JTextField> getVersionActuelleFields () {
    return versionActuelleFields ;
}    
//class code

for (Application app : model.getCheckedApplications()) {
    //Other code
    JTextField nouvellesNaturesField = new JTextField(
            30);
    nouvellesNaturesField.setName("nouvellesNatures"
            + app.getCode88());
    nouvellesNaturesFields.put(app, nouvellesNaturesField);

    //Other code and same for your new nature fields
}
result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
        "Valeurs de cette version",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Then when the user clicks the confirm button, using the property accessor `getNouvellesNaturesFields()`or `getVersionActuelleFields()` you can iterate all the fields created, like so:

```
for (Map.Entry<Application, JTextField> entry: myMap.entries()) {
    //Do something here
}
```

Or you could also get them via:

```
for (Application app : model.getCheckedApplications()) {
    List<JTextField> data = myMap.get(app);
    for(JTextField field : data) {
        field.getText();
    }
}
```

Since the key value probably won't be unique, I used an [`ArrayListMultiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html), but if it would be unique, then a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) should suffice

Comment: The hashmap solution with application code in key and the Array of 2 JTextField in value works great in my context. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You assign the Jtextfield value to a string using the getText() method e.g below

```
String texfield = JTextField.getText();
```

Subsequently you use the String textfield wherever you want. And to get the right jtextfield you have to get text from the textfield you want for example you have four Jtexfield. Assuming they are JTextField1, JTextField2, JTextField3 and JTextField4. To get the value of JTextField3 you have

```
String texfield = JTextField3.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

The values should be in the JTextFields you created:

versionActuelleField
nouvellesNaturesField

Also, you might want to look at [ParamDialog](https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/dialogs/ParamDialog.java), which I implemented to be a generic solution to this question.

## EDIT

Yes I see now that you are creating these `JTextFields` in a loop. So you need to create a `Collection`, I'd suggest a `Map<String, JTextField>` where you could map all of your application names to the matching `JTextField`, as well as iterate over the collection to get all application names / `JTextFields`.

Comment: The OP doesn't have access to those fields as they were created in a for loop, the problem is that they aren't storing references to those fields anywhere and are lost upon exiting the for loop